# Javascript Regex 1-10

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regex that can get from 1-10 and i have been having trouble

I have tried :

```
/^[1-9]|10$/ //this will matches out 1-9 but not 10
/^10|[1-9]$/ //this will matches 10 but no 1-9 digits
```

I feel weird because i have seen this question before and people said either of these expression should work. Any ideas of another way to get any # from 1-10?

Comment: Put parenthesis surrounding the alternation, but before the anchors. This way, the anchors will apply the both alternations. As it is now, the ^ applies to 10 and the [1-9] applies to $. Even as it is now, both should match, but it could match asdfasdfsdf`10` or `5`asdfasdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to match a string containing a number 1–10 and nothing else, you were close with `/^[1-9]|10$/`. The problem here is that the alternation `|` includes the `^` and `$` characters, i.e. this expression will match either `^[1-9]` (any string beginning with 1–9`) or`10$` (any string ending with 10). Parentheses solve this neatly:

```
/^([1-9]|10)$/
```

See it in action below:

```js
const regex = /^([1-9]|10)$/gm; // `gm` flags for demo only; read below
const str = `1
2
3
4
foo
5
6
7
8
9
10`;

let m;
while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
  console.log('Found match:', m[0]);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

The snippet uses the `g` and `m` flags to find all of the matches across multiple lines. `m` makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line rather than the beginning and end of the string. For your use case you probably don't want either flag.

Comment: With what input? Try `'9'.match(/^([1-9]|10)$/)` in your console. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your specific use case, I don't see a reason to include ^ and & here, which requires that the number is surrounded by a start and end of line. Even if your inner regex was correct, it wouldn't match the '6' in: 'I have a 6 year old son.'

Instead, surround the inner regex with \b (a word boundary). So, to use Jordan's example, \b([1-9]|10)\b would match all numbers from 1-10. To use regex in javascript, you need to utilize one of several functions that accept it as an argument, or methods that can be called on it:

```js
let regex = /\b([1-9]|10)\b/;

console.log('I have a 6 year old son.'.match(regex)[0]);
console.log('I have a six year old son.'.match(regex));

console.log('I have a 6 year old son.'.replace(regex, 'six'));

console.log(regex.test('I have a 6 year old son.'));
console.log(regex.test('I have a six year old son.'));
```